# How to pass parameter value In .aspx page to Sql Query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, webforms, aspx-user-control

I am working in ASP.NET C# source, in that I have a process to pass parameter value from an ASPX page.

In the below code I need to pass `a.cYear` and `AssignedDate` through ASP.NET controls.

Note : I'm not using .aspx.cs page, I am creating this code in .aspx page.

I am passing like this in .aspx.cs page,

```
    bolMachineStatus.cyear = Request.Cookies["BCookies"]["SessionFinancialYear"];
    bolMachineStatus.AssignedDate = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString();
```

This is the full source,
in this I have passed values directly,

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Calendar2_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection strConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BConnection"].ToString());            
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        strConn.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE #PendingMachineStatus(cMBrnCode NVARCHAR(2),cMBrnName NVARCHAR(25),
                    cYear NVARCHAR(4),nCallNo INT,Date Datetime)
                    INSERT INTO #PendingMachineStatus
                    select c.cMBrnCode,c.cMBrnName,b.cYear,b.nCallNo,
                    MAX(b.StatusDate) as Date
                    from SvCallHead a
                    INNER JOIN MachineStatus b on a.cYear = b.cYear AND a.nCallNo = b.nCallNo
                    INNER JOIN SvMainBrn c on a.cMBrnCode=c.cMBrnCode
                    where b.cYear='**2017**'
                    and a.cCallSuff = 'A' AND a.cCallEnd = 'N' AND  a.cServType = 'A'
                    AND a.cStatFlg  <> 'C'
                    GROUP BY c.cMBrnCode,c.cMBrnName,b.cYear,b.nCallNo

                    CREATE TABLE #MachineStatus(cMBrnCode NVARCHAR(7),cMBrnName NVARCHAR(100),cYear NVARCHAR(4),nCallNo INT,
                    MainStatus varchar(10),Status varchar(10),cSvPrCode NVARCHAR(10),AssignedDate Datetime,
                    IsSMS BIT)
                    INSERT INTO #MachineStatus
                    SELECT a.cMBrnCode,a.cMBrnName,a.cYear,a.nCallNo,b.MainStatus,b.MachineStatus,b.cSvPrCode,b.AssignedDate,b.IsSMS
                    FROM #PendingMachineStatus a
                    INNER JOIN MachineStatus b ON a.nCallNo=b.nCallNo AND a.Date=b.StatusDate

                    select COUNT(*) AS Count,
                    CASE d.cSvPrCode
                    WHEN '0' THEN NULL
                    ELSE d.cSvPrCode
                    END cSvPrCode,
                    CASE d.AssignedDate
                    WHEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN NULL
                    ELSE d.AssignedDate
                    END AS AssignedDate,
                    DAY(d.AssignedDate) AS Day,
                    MONTH(d.AssignedDate) AS Month,
                    f.cSvPrName
                    from SvCallHead a
                    INNER JOIN SvMainBrn b on a.cMBrnCode=b.cMBrnCode
                    LEFT JOIN SvDelrMast c on a.cDelrCode=c.cDelrCode
                    LEFT JOIN #MachineStatus d on a.cYear=d.cYear and a.nCallNo=d.nCallNo
                    LEFT JOIN SvSvPrMast f on d.cSvPrCode=f.cSvPrCode
                    where a.cYear='**2017**' and **d.AssignedDate='2018/03/15'** and a.cCallSuff = 'A' AND a.cCallEnd= 'N'
                    AND a.cServType= 'A' AND a.cStatFlg<> 'C' AND f.cSvPrName<>'NULL'
                    group by d.cSvPrCode,d.AssignedDate,f.cSvPrName
                    order by AssignedDate asc

                    drop table #PendingMachineStatus
                    drop table #MachineStatus";
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, strConn);
        da.Fill(ds);
        strConn.Close();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            DataGrid1.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            DataGrid1.Visible = true;
            DataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            DataGrid1.DataBind();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you put that in a stored procedure and make it parameterized. For now, you can look into string.Format to pass the values.

Something like:

```
           var str = string.Format(@"CREATE TABLE #PendingMachineStatus(cMBrnCode NVARCHAR(2),cMBrnName NVARCHAR(25),
                cYear NVARCHAR(4),nCallNo INT,Date Datetime)
                INSERT INTO #PendingMachineStatus
                select c.cMBrnCode,c.cMBrnName,b.cYear,b.nCallNo,
                MAX(b.StatusDate) as Date
                from SvCallHead a
                INNER JOIN MachineStatus b on a.cYear = b.cYear AND a.nCallNo = b.nCallNo
                INNER JOIN SvMainBrn c on a.cMBrnCode=c.cMBrnCode
                where b.cYear={0}
                and a.cCallSuff = 'A' AND a.cCallEnd = 'N' AND  a.cServType = 'A'
                AND a.cStatFlg  <> 'C'
                GROUP BY c.cMBrnCode,c.cMBrnName,b.cYear,b.nCallNo

                CREATE TABLE #MachineStatus(cMBrnCode NVARCHAR(7),cMBrnName NVARCHAR(100),cYear NVARCHAR(4),nCallNo INT,
                MainStatus varchar(10),Status varchar(10),cSvPrCode NVARCHAR(10),AssignedDate Datetime,
                IsSMS BIT)
                INSERT INTO #MachineStatus
                SELECT a.cMBrnCode,a.cMBrnName,a.cYear,a.nCallNo,b.MainStatus,b.MachineStatus,b.cSvPrCode,b.AssignedDate,b.IsSMS
                FROM #PendingMachineStatus a
                INNER JOIN MachineStatus b ON a.nCallNo=b.nCallNo AND a.Date=b.StatusDate

                select COUNT(*) AS Count,
                CASE d.cSvPrCode
                WHEN '0' THEN NULL
                ELSE d.cSvPrCode
                END cSvPrCode,
                CASE d.AssignedDate
                WHEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN NULL
                ELSE d.AssignedDate
                END AS AssignedDate,
                DAY(d.AssignedDate) AS Day,
                MONTH(d.AssignedDate) AS Month,
                f.cSvPrName
                from SvCallHead a
                INNER JOIN SvMainBrn b on a.cMBrnCode=b.cMBrnCode
                LEFT JOIN SvDelrMast c on a.cDelrCode=c.cDelrCode
                LEFT JOIN #MachineStatus d on a.cYear=d.cYear and a.nCallNo=d.nCallNo
                LEFT JOIN SvSvPrMast f on d.cSvPrCode=f.cSvPrCode
                where a.cYear={0} and d.AssignedDate={1} and a.cCallSuff = 'A' AND a.cCallEnd= 'N'
                AND a.cServType= 'A' AND a.cStatFlg<> 'C' AND f.cSvPrName<>'NULL'
                group by d.cSvPrCode,d.AssignedDate,f.cSvPrName
                order by AssignedDate asc

                drop table #PendingMachineStatus
                drop table #MachineStatus", Request.Cookies["BCookies"]["SessionFinancialYear"], Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString());
```

Comment: Don't do it like this, this method is vulnerable to SQL INJECTION. Use SqlParameters like in the example: https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlParameter

> ```
>     //
>     // The name we are trying to match.
>     //
>     string dogName = "Fido";
>     //
>     // Use preset string for connection and open it.
>     //
>     string connectionString =
>         ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
>     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
>     {
>         connection.Open();
>         //
>         // Description of SQL command:
>         // 1. It selects all cells from rows matching the name.
>         // 2. It uses LIKE operator because Name is a Text field.
>         // 3. @Name must be added as a new SqlParameter.
>         //
>         using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
>             "SELECT * FROM Dogs1 WHERE Name LIKE @Name", connection))
>         {
>             //
>             // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
>             //
>             command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", dogName));
>             //
>             // Read in the SELECT results.
>             //
>             SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
>             while (reader.Read())
>             {
>                 int weight = reader.GetInt32(0);
>                 string name = reader.GetString(1);
>                 string breed = reader.GetString(2);
>                 Console.WriteLine("Weight = {0}, Name = {1}, Breed = {2}",
>                     weight,
>                     name,
>                     breed);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

More details in the example: https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Answer (score 0):

This is high risk. SQL Injection is top security risk from OWASP.org for 2017.

- You should create a Stored Procedure using the following link: [Create a SP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- You should then use ADO.Net/Entity Framework to execute the stored procedure through your code. The only thing you should be passing from client to server is through SQL parameters. For ADO use the link: [Call a SP using ADO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041846/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-using-ado-net)